# Python: How can I make that my funtion print once?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have this funtion:

```
def encontrar(data_,departureAirportCode_,departureTime_,arrivalAirportCode_,arrivalTime_):
    for i in range(len(data_flights)):
        data=data_[i]["flights"]
        for k in range(len(data)):
            departureAirportCode=data[k]["departureAirportCode"]
            departureTime=data[k]["departureTime"]
            arrivalAirportCode=data[k]["arrivalAirportCode"]
            arrivalTime=data[k]["arrivalTime"]            
            if departureAirportCode==departureAirportCode_ and departureTime==departureTime_ and arrivalAirportCode==arrivalAirportCode_ and arrivalTime==arrivalTime_:
                code=data_[i]["flights"][k]["itinerary"][0]["flightCode"]
                print(code)
    else:
        print("There is no flights on that date")
```

that print the result (an interget) like this:

```
encontrar(data_flights,"SCL","2022-01-11T15:40:00","PMC","2022-01-11T17:20:00")
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
401
There is no flights on that date
```

instead only: 401
thanks in advance, i'm a bit newbie to python yet :)
thanks in advance, i'm a bit newbie to python yet :)

Comment: Why are u using length of dataflights inside function

Comment: Your print statement is inside the loop, so every time the loop passes it, it prints - you could put it outside the loop for a start?

Comment: and the else part is paired wrongly

Comment: If you just want to filter data with function argument, try use `filter` with `lambda`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a break statement within the for loop like this:

```py
def encontrar(data_,departureAirportCode_,departureTime_,arrivalAirportCode_,arrivalTime_):
    for i in range(len(data_flights)):
        data=data_[i]["flights"]
        for k in range(len(data)):
            departureAirportCode=data[k]["departureAirportCode"]
            departureTime=data[k]["departureTime"]
            arrivalAirportCode=data[k]["arrivalAirportCode"]
            arrivalTime=data[k]["arrivalTime"]            
            if departureAirportCode==departureAirportCode_ and departureTime==departureTime_ and arrivalAirportCode==arrivalAirportCode_ and arrivalTime==arrivalTime_:
                code=data_[i]["flights"][k]["itinerary"][0]["flightCode"]
                print(code)
                break

    else:
        print("There is no flights on that date")
```

Comment: I think continue is preferred here in this case.. Instead of break as it breaks the loop..

Comment: @Madenraj sure, but he is trying to print once. Continue wouldn't solve that, he doesn't need the loop to run once he's found the airport code as I understand it. Also, the else with the for loop in python requires a break in the loop to not run.

Comment: Got it, a clear question might help all..